# Bounty Awarding in case of expiration of bounty duration

Tags: feature-request, bounty

As per the rules of bounty,

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or
>   more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the
>   oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria,
>   no bounty is awarded to anyone.

I answered a question with bounty but I think the question was very much specific to using a technology where the asker was stuck somewhere while implementing it in his own project. I feel the question was not "so visible" even after the bounty because of the nature of the question. Also, I was the only one to answer the question.

Though I had answered the question and I think with the given help the asker would have get around the question.

Now coming back to the rules I feel its unfair that the answerer needs to have a minimum of 2 scores to get half the bounty.

If the visibility/or lack of interest is the problem, then why should be a bounty be just thrown away instead of being given.

If this needs to be related the scores on the answer, then I think this constant '2' must be related to the scores on the question also.

Like this constant should be at least 'half' of the score of the question.
i.e. If the question has 2 score the answer must have a score of 1

Answer (score 1):

Your proposal is not any fairer than the current rule. I've seen quite a few question where the question itself was a clear and interesting one, so it got a lot of upvotes but the answers that could be posted were not easily to evaluate because they required extremely specialized knowledge. It was not rare in such cases that the answer would get much less upvotes than the question, certainly not enough to reach half the score of the question.

I'm 100% certain that if we were to implement what you suggest, we'd get as many complaints on Meta about unfairness, if not more. In other words, the change would not improve the *overall* picture.

Answer (score 0):

> Like this constant should be at least 'half' of the score of the
>   question. i.e. If the question has 2 score the answer must have a
>   score of 1

Why shouldn't an answer with a score of 2 get the bounty when the question has a score 6?

Why should an answer with a score of 0, meaning that no one that saw it found it useful, get awarded at all? Just because it exists?

With this rule an answer that doesn't even address the problem in the question could get a bounty if the question also had a score of 0, while a good answer with up votes wouldn't get the bounty if it didn't have half the score of the question.

This seems much, much more unfair than the idea that the answer should have been judged to be useful to the community to get the bounty when the OP doesn't award it.