# How much time does our Community User generally take to award the bounty in case of bounty not being awarded within 7 days (plus the grace period)?

Tags: support, bounty, community-user

How much time does our Community User generally take to award the bounty in case of bounty not being awarded within 7 days (plus the grace period)?

The second clause at [How is a bounty awarded?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) says:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

Currently, I can see the status as follows:

[image: Screenshot of bounty notice saying the bounty and grace period have ended]

I have looked for the answer in [Bounty Awarding in case of expiration of bounty duration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323548/bounty-awarding-in-case-of-expiration-of-bounty-duration) and [Why is there a grace period for bounties?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323826/why-is-there-a-grace-period-for-bounties), but none of them answer my question.

So, how much time does our Community User generally take to award the bounty in case of bounty not being awarded within 7 days (plus the grace period)?

Comment: This is done by a scheduled job. Are you asking how often that job runs?

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, even this information will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've checked the timelines of a couple of questions where this happened, found with [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/795163/timelines-for-questions-with-auto-awarded-bounty-of-50-25-points):

```
Bounty start      +7 days +24 hrs   Bounty end + award
Jan 20 at 1:03    Jan 28 at 1:03    Jan 28 at 2:33
Jan 19 at 2:10    Jan 27 at 2:10    Jan 27 at 3:31
Jan 19 at 18:29   Jan 27 at 18:29   Jan 27 at 19:33
Jan 18 at 17:45   Jan 26 at 17:45   Jan 26 at 19:28
Jan 18 at 6:44    Jan 26 at 6:44    Jan 26 at 8:28
Jan 18 at 3:04    Jan 26 at 3:04    Jan 26 at 4:27
```

It looks like a (cron)job which runs every hour, but it instead of a 24 hour grace period, it seems to use 25 hours (maybe to compensate for possible Daylight Savings Time shifts?). The removal of the bounty notice and the award of the bounty happen simultaneously. Only when the job runs, the 'default situation' is identified.

To further science this topic, you could try setting a bounty and awarding it within an hour *after* the 24 hour grace period ends.

Comment: This is the _select query_ and pretty much close to the info/trigger I wanted to understand. What I still need to understand is, if at all the default case (_bounty not awarded_) is identified why is the _action_ not taking place simultaneously. Is the action handled by a _cronjob_ which is triggered at certain intervals or is that manual?