# Answered a bountied question, answer is unaccepted and at -1, am I going to get that bounty?

Tags: support, bounty, community-user

How can the fate of a bounty depend on miracles?

The second clause at [*How is a bounty awarded?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) says:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

Emphasizing the clause post *7 days (plus the grace period)* it stands as :

*The highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted).*

My questions are :

- Who can be among the potential users to cast an upvote on each bounty raised?
- Taking OP into consideration at times there can be only 1 upvote, so who can be the second upvoter?

I have looked for the answer in the following posts :

- [Bounty Awarding in case of expiration of bounty duration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323548/bounty-awarding-in-case-of-expiration-of-bounty-duration)
- [Why is there a grace period for bounties?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323826/why-is-there-a-grace-period-for-bounties)
- [How much time does our Community User generally take to award the bounty in case of bounty not being awarded within 7 days (plus the grace period)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362761/how-much-time-does-our-community-user-generally-take-to-award-the-bounty-in-case)

None of them answers my question *How can the fate of a bounty depend on miracles?*

*Update* :

The question is regarding the bounty on the discussion [*Selenium grid sessions not applied*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48357644/selenium-grid-sessions-not-applied) . My answer was downvoted right from revision 1 of [*Selenium grid sessions not applied*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48357644/1) . As you can see within the comments that OP now agrees to my answer/inputs but the *downvote* was not retracted. Hence I don't fore-see a chance of *acceptance* even, where as the *Grace period ends in 8 hours*

Comment: My brain hurts. Can you make your question a bit clearer? It's not entirely evident what you are on about. You think it is impossible for an answer to receive two up-votes?

Comment: It seems like you're confusing bounties and upvotes somehow. They're completely unrelated mechanisms. Votes happen independent of any bounty, and a bounty is not itself a vote (or an avenue for voting).

Comment: @JeroenMostert If you have a look at the statement _The highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted)._ of-coarse _bounties_ needs _upvotes_ to be awarded in default case.

Comment: @yivi When dealing with low volume tags at times it can be impossible _for a bounty answer to receive two up-votes in a span of 7 days_

Comment: @DebanjanB: *answers* need upvotes. You can't vote on *bounties*, those are eventually awarded (or not) to an answer based on upvotes. I'm not trying to be pedantic, I genuinely don't understand what your beef is. Is your point specifically about answers created after the bounty started compared to answers before that, something like that?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, you said it right _awarded (or not) to an answer based on upvotes_ . My question is about generation of _2 upvotes_ in a low volume tag where some times it can be impossible. CodeCaster 's answer below throws some more light on the fact.

Comment: Keep in mind these rules are only even an issue if the bounty is not manually awarded by the person who made the bounty. This is not the most common case. You'd typically expect the person setting the bounty to actually *care* about their bounty going to the answer *they* think most valuable, so the exact rules for what should happen if they don't bother are not as important.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are right on target now. Fundamentally, there is a lot of difference between _expect the person to care_ and the _reality_ with respect to a new user on _SO_ dealing in low volume tags. Hence appears to me as being _depends on miracle._

Comment: New users don't have the reputation to raise bounties in the first place. Please elaborate on why you expect "miracles" to happen.

Comment: So your problem is specifically with auto-awarded bounties on questions in low volume tags? Can you point to/work out a question (a real one if possible, though a hypothetical example if nothing better comes to mind) where awarding the bounty went or would go "wrong" in your opinion, and how you think it should have been awarded? That would make your question a whole lot more concrete and a whole lot less based on guessing what you're at.

Comment: Even on low traffic tags, is there even such a thing as a low-traffic bountied question?

Comment: @JeroenMostert updated the question with the real instance. Thanks a ton for your attention to my details. As I continue to to pick up _How meta SO works_ I don't have an option either on _how you think it should have been awarded?_ But of-coarse a logic should be in place.

Comment: This is one of those "you are out of luck" instances. It's not possible for the site to guess that your -1 answer is actually good, helps the OP, and should have been accepted and awarded the bounty -- that's entirely on the shoulders of the OP. And the OP could fail to award the bounty/retract the vote out of no carelessness or maliciousness, but simply because (say) they had a personal emergency. It sucks, but you can't get 'em all. It would be much worse if the site auto-awarded the bounty to an incorrect -1 answer and thereby legitimize it because "there's no better choice".

Comment: @JeroenMostert You seem to be great visionary. Having said that I will like to put for the record that the rate of _Missing to reward_ is rising exponentially and I have learnt to live with it. Thanks again for your valuable time, patience, suggestions. Good day.

Comment: _Growing exponentially_? Care to share any stats on that?

Comment: So you received a down-vote, which may or may not have been cast by the OP; and may not receive the bounty for the question... and you come here to throw a tantrum about _miracles_? That question got more than a hundred views, if your answer didn't get any love is nobody's fault.

Comment: @DebanjanB Maybe making your question clearer would help? Because it seems like the crux of what you're asking here is a change in the criteria for low traffic tags....And you go on a LOT of weird tangential points, and talk about concepts in a "non-stack" way... which makes it very hard to follow... like talking about upvotes on bounties

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you break the sentence up, it becomes quite apparent what's being meant:

- The highest voted answer
- created after the bounty started
- with [the answer having] a minimum score of 2
- will be awarded half the bounty amount
- (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted).

So no, there are no miracles involved, and you can't vote on bounties. Only on comments, questions and answers.

So:

> Who can be among the potential users to cast an upvote on each bounty raised?

Nobody, but everybody who has those privileges can vote on the posted answers.

> Taking OP into consideration at times there can be only 1 upvote, so who can be the second upvoter?

Anyone who has the privilege to vote on answers.

---

As for your edits and comments, I think your question can now simply be restated as such:

> I posted an answer on a bountied question. My answer currently sits at a score of -1, and it doesn't look like the OP is going to award the bounty to my answer - and the automatic bounty award only considers answers having a score of at least +2, so it won't be auto-awarded.
>
> How can I earn this bounty, knowing my answer does in fact solve the OP's issue?

It's a shame if you answer a bountied question and you're not awarded the bounty, but not getting the reputation you think you deserve is a risk when posting a question or an answer anyway. The criteria for automatically awarding a bounty were set for a reason.

Just hope your answer actually is correct and applies to a broad audience as opposed as to just the OP, and over time will gain the upvotes it deserves.

Comment: Maybe that sentence needs some more commas. "The highest voted answer, created after the bounty started and with a minimum score of 2, will be awarded ..."

Comment: Add an oxford comma as well: _"after the bounty started, and"_

Comment: @CodeCaster I am interested in the last 2 points from your answer. _Nobody, but everybody_ and _Anyone who has the privilege to vote on answers_ so the question is [who bells the cat?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belling_the_cat) ?

Comment: @DebanjanB: "*so the question is who bells the cat? ?*" Your analogy makes no sense. "Who bells the cat" is based on the fact that getting within arms length of a cat is a dangerous thing for a mouse. By contrast, voting requires no such investment. Your (presumed) problem is not that people are afraid to vote for your answer, but that there's *nobody around* to do so.

Comment: @DebanjanB how do you think you got all the votes you did on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498) you don't have 19 sockpuppets do you?